# Using set command to display a frequently updated number

Tags: batch-file, set, echo

still working on my batch journal entry script and cant figure out how to have this specific command frequently update this line the more files I add into my journal folder 
currently when i fill in anything past entries= it just displays an echo of what is written
it would be preferable if the answer included the ability to count files in a specific directory

(I.E i have a folder called JournalEntries and my current path for accessing this is %cd%\JournalEntries)
Edit: Apologies for me being a little unclear, here's an better example

```
    set entries= "." /w /s
    echo There are currently a total of %entries% 
    entries
```

Output:
There are currently a total of "." /w /s entries

Desired Output: 
There are currently a total of (amount of files in directory) entries

Comment: but you have no value set for `%entries%` so nothing will be dislayed?

Comment: when i enter anything past the "entries=" part I receive an echo instead of what I want
I tried using the "." /w /s just leaving it with the current directory but all I get is "." /w /s when the line 
    echo There are currently a total of %entries% entries

Comment: I am confused, enter anything past entries? Can you edit your question and clarify?

Comment: There you go, hope that clarifies better that I dont know what Im doing lol

Comment: If you don't know what you are doing, you cannot explain it to us. If you cannot explain it to us, we cannot help you.

Comment: Yes that is in fact how trying to learn/teach something new can go, I apologize for being somewhat unclear with my questions, trying my best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a little unclear, but seems you want to see the number of files and then set as a variable:

```
@echo off
for /f %%i in ('dir JournalEntries ^| findstr "File(s)"') do set entries=%%i
echo There are currently a total of %entries%
```

Comment: This worked! Thanks, I'm new to batch scripting and dont really know all the variables and everything. Appreciate it!

Comment: I suggest you open `cmd` and search some of the help to assist you in learning it quick. `for /?`, `set /?` and `findstr /?`